# What is the meaning behind FreeBSD bootloader ASCII art daemon letters?

Tags: freebsd, history, ascii-art

FreeBSD bootloader includes an ASCII art daemon. Is there any meaning behind the letters "s, y, o", or is just a random choice?

[image]

Comment: Because those letters have the shape they want?

Comment: I get the shape, but I thought there might have been something deeper to it. If it's just the shape aren't there better options? To me it seems more complex than it might appear.

Comment: perhaps a fancy invocation of something like [jp2a](https://github.com/cslarsen/jp2a)?

Comment: though it seems to be the way the art has been created, it doesn't answer the question. thanks anyway :)

Comment: If you don't get an answer, ask Devin Teske, who created it. http://devinteske.com/wp/new-freebsd-boot-loader-menu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The choice of letters is based on how the boot loader font renders each character

Shout out to [Devin Teske](https://twitter.com/devinteske) for clarification!

Here's the [thread](https://twitter.com/devinteske/status/962558331377168384).

Answer (score 4):

It's just basic [ASCII art](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ASCII_art), much like if I wanted an arrow I could use for instance `>---->`.  They use the character that most resembles the shape they want for the picture they are "drawing" with character cells.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will wait a little to see if somebody has more info. If not, I will accept it.